# How to include product key in an MS installation DVD

Tags: pre-pidded

I have an MSDN subscription, so I get access to all MS products. I would like to slipstream my installation media to include a valid product key.

Can you give me an example on how to do this? So that the product key is automatically filled in I think Microsoft called this - pre pidded.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are 2 tools for pre-installation Windows configuration and component removal at your choice.

use [**nLite**](http://www.nliteos.com/index.html) for Windows 2000, XP x86/x64 and Server 2003 x86/x64

use [**vLite**](http://www.vlite.net/) for Windows Vista and 7

> Main features are:
>
> hotfix, language pack and driver
>   integration
>
> component removal
>
> **unattended setup**
>
> tweaks
>
> split/merge Vista installation CDs
>
> create ISO and burn bootable CD/DVD

Comment: There's also various guides on the internet detailing how to create unattended MS Office/Visual Studio installations as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are after is an unattended install.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a place to start:

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=291997

p.s. the guide is for XP, but the same principles should apply